# What is it called in Java when you create an instance on the fly?

Tags: java, language-features, anonymous-class

In code,

```
class MyObject {
   public String doThing() {
      return "doh";
   }
}

class MyClass {
   private myObject = null;
   public MyClass() {
       myObject = new MyObject() {
           public String doThing() {
              return "huh?";
           }
       };
   }
```

What is it called when myObject is assigned a new object?  I'm technically trying to find out if the 'doThing' overrides the method from MyObject, or if it redefines it, but I have no idea what to search on to find an answer - and no idea what question to ask without knowing what it's called when you create a new instance of an object on the fly and give it an implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are creating an *anonymous inner class* that is a subclass of `MyObject`, so yes, you are overriding the `doThing` method, if is that what you ask.

By the way, anonymous classes are like named classes, they have their own bytecode in their `.class` file, that is named like their enclosing class suffixed with a dollar sign and an number.

If you want to experiment by yourself, you can use the method `getClass()` of `myObject` and extract information about it, like the name, parent, implemented interfaces, generic arguments, etc.

Answer (score 3):

That's called an anonymous inner class.

Given that the `doThing()` method has the same signature as a public method in its superclass, it overrides it.

The best way to be sure is to add the @Override annotation to the method in the subclass: the compiler will generate a compilation error if the method with this annotation doesn't override any method.

Answer (score 2):

The name for this structure is [Anonymous inner class](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue002.html)

You'll find plenty of docs about these with Google

Answer (score 1):

In Java all non-final instance methods are subject to override (i.e. virtual). This equally applies to inner classes, so your code overrides `MyObject`'s `doThing()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `doThing()` method is overridden. This is equivalent to an anonymous class that is inheriting the behavior of MyObject and then overriding it.